# Delete content between 2 lines

Tags: powershell

I have a pacfile which I am trying to update and need to remove content between two strings; the strings themselves should be kept:

```
 // OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS
```

and

```
// END OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS
```

example:

```
// OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS
  if (isInNet(hostip, "23.103.132.0","255.255.252.0") ||    //EOP
  isInNet(hostip, "23.103.136.0","255.255.248.0") ||    //EOP
  isInNet(hostip, "23.103.144.0","255.255.240.0") ||    //EOP
  isInNet(hostip, "23.103.191.0","255.255.255.0") ||    //EOP
// END OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS
```

I want to remove the lines between the top and bottom lines

```
$Pacfile = Get-ChildItem .\o365.pac | Get-Content -Raw
$startstring= " \/\/ OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS(.*? )\/\/END OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS"
$NewPacfile = [regex]::match($Pacfile, $startstring).Groups[1].value
$NewPacfile
```

Comment: You could just do a replace. Replace start*end with startend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$regex=@'
(?ms)^(\s*// OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS\s*?\r?\n).*?\r?\n(\s*// END OFFICE 365 DIRECT ACCESS\s*)
'@
(Get-Content -Raw .\o365.pac) -replace $regex, '$1$2'
```

- `-replace $regex, '$1$2'` replaces what the regex matched with what the 1st (`$1`) and 2nd capture groups (`$2`) (parenthesized subexpression, `(...)`) inside of it matched.
  Here, these capture groups capture the strings enclosing the range of interest.
- `(?ms)` sets both the **m**ulti-line and the **s**ingle-line option for the regex:

  - `m` means that `^` and `$` should match the start and end of each *line* rather than the input string as a whole.
  - `s` means that metacharacter `.` should match `\n` characters too, so that an expression such as `.*` can be used to match *across lines*.
- `\r?\n` matches a single line break, both the CRLF and the LF variety.
- `.*?` matches the part to *remove*; note the non-greedy modifier (`?`) following `.*`, which ensures that the *next* occurrence of the end string is matched.